# Read database from IO context and update UI from Main context in Kotlin

Tags: database, kotlin, user-interface

Still a bit new to Kotlin and coroutines, so I want to learn best practices. The following code seems to work as expected in it's original context, though the naming has been tweaked here. The list of widgets is retrieved from the database, and the UI is updated correctly.
My main question is, in `updateList` is it approprate to use `withContext (Dispatchers.Main)` to access the UI from a job on the IO context? Feels a bit kludgy at first blush, but it does seem to work as expected.

```
class WidgetListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var db: AppDatabase
    private lateinit var getListJob: Job
    private lateinit var widgetList: List<WidgetRecord>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_widget_list)

        runBlocking  {
            db = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "Widget.db")
                .createFromAsset("database/prepop_db.sqlite").build()
        }
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.widget_recycler_view)
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.applicationContext)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

        updateList()
    }

    private fun updateList() {
        getListJob = GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO) {
            widgetList = db.widgetDao().getAllWidgets()

            // HERE'S THE SECTION IN QUESTION
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.deck_recycler_view)
                var widgetListAdapter = WidgetListAdapter(widgetList)
                recyclerView.adapter = widgetListAdapter
                widgetListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }


    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        runBlocking {
            getListJob.join()
        }
        
        // PLEASE NOTE: I know you wouldn't normally destroy the database
        // like this. The whole point of this Activity is simply to test
        // loading and displaying the contents of a prepopulated database.
        this.applicationContext.deleteDatabase("Widgets.db")
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that makes it kludgy is using GlobalScope, [which is discouraged by the coroutines design lead](https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc). In this case, if this were a very long-running job, you would be leaking your UI elements because they are captured by the coroutine.

Also, since you are using Room, you can make your DAO's `getAllWidgets()` a suspend function, in which case, there's no reason to use a specific dispatcher to call it. A properly composed suspend function doesn't block the dispatcher it is called from, so you never should have to specify a dispatcher to call a suspend function. The proper way to do this would be:

```
private fun updateList() {
    getListJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
        widgetList = db.widgetDao().getAllWidgets()
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.deck_recycler_view)
        var widgetListAdapter = WidgetListAdapter(widgetList)
        recyclerView.adapter = widgetListAdapter
        widgetListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

No Dispatcher specifying needed at all, because the coroutine doesn't call any blocking code and `lifecycleScope` defaults to `Dispatchers.Main`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info. There are a couple of things in particular in your answer that I simply wasn't aware of.
I didn't realize there was a `lifeCycleScope` available as a member. That's very handy.
I also didn't realize that a dispatcher isn't needed to call a `suspend` function. I think the relationships between dispatchers, coroutine scopes, and suspending functions have been the hardest part to wrap my head around, but this information helps a lot.

Cheers.

Comment: Also, just to note for anyone who reads this later, you have to add `lifecycle-runtime` as a dependency in build.gradle to use the `lifecycleScope` member. [https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle)

Comment: Yes, it took a while for it all to click for me because there are so many components to a coroutine.

Comment: Since the documentation for lifecycleScope says that "This scope will be cancelled when the Lifecycle is destroyed", I guess it's unnecessary to call `getListJob.join()` in `onDestroy`, correct? Or would it be considered best practice to wait for jobs to finish when possible?

Comment: If you start a job in lifecycleScope, its because you are fetching something for that Activity or Fragment, so presumably you don't care about the result and want it to be cancelled when the Activity or Fragment is destroyed. The cancellation is done automatically because lifecycleScope is automatically cancelled in the onDestroy phase. Joining it waits for the result, but there's no point if you are just going to throw the result away. If you join, you are holding the Activity/Fragment and everything it references in memory until the job is done.

Comment: Also, `runBlocking` has no place *anywhere* in an Android application. Its only two intended purposes are for use in unit tests and directly in the `main` function of a JVM app. Blocking a main thread locks the UI and can cause an ANR error.